# RegEx matching a valid date Presto

Tags: sql, regex, date, presto, trino

For the table below, I'd like to extract the  `available from date`  from the `additional_info` string. I know there is a **regexp_extract_all(string, pattern)** function in Presto but not quite sure how to extract a date from string.

FYI:

- Dates are always in same format
- There can only be one date in the `additional_info` column
- Rows with no date in `additional_info` column have null in date column

table

```
product_id   additional_info
325245       New, contact for more information, available from 01.01.2020
635255       Used, available from 06.11.2020
422632        New, contact for more information
```

desired output_table

```
product_id     available_date 
325245         01.01.2020
635255         06.11.2020
422632
```

Comment: (1) `additional_info` looks like a string, not an array.  (2) Are the dates always in the same format?  (3) What if there are multiple dates or no date?

Comment: I have edited my post. Dates are always in the same format and if there can only be one date or no date, in which case the date col is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dates are always in this format, a very straightforward solution could be:

```
SELECT
   product_id
   , regexp_extract(additional_info, '(\d\d.\d\d.\d\d\d\d)')
FROM table
```

It will return the first substring matched by your capturing group `(betweenbrackets)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dot in regexp means any character. To match dot literally in regexp you need to shield it with backslash `\.`

```
SELECT
     product_id,
     regexp_extract(additional_info, '(\d\d\.\d\d\.\d{4})')
FROM table
```

If you want to allow different delimiters, not only dots, use character class `[]`. For example, dot or dash:

```
SELECT
     product_id,
     regexp_extract(additional_info, '(\d\d[.-]\d\d[.-]\d{4})')
FROM table
```